# retain cycle with target-selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain-cycle

I am new to retain cycle which I am confused if my situation falls into.

I have a singleton class

Singleton.h

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance;

- (void)doSomethingWithData:(NSDictionary *)data untilDoneReturnToTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;

@end
```

Singleton.m

```
@implementation RequestSingleton

static Singleton *shared = nil;

#pragma mark - System

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Interface

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Singleton alloc] init];
    });

    return shared;
}

- (void)doSomethingWithData:(NSDictionary *)data untilDoneReturnToTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {
    [someClass doSomething:data
       completionHandler: ^{
        if ([target respondsToSelector:selector]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
                                   [target performSelector:selector
                                                withObject:someObject]; // is this a retain-cycle?
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
                               }

     }];    
}
```

Now in a view controller, I call `doSomethingWithData:untilDoneReturnToTarget:selector:` defined in `Singleton` class:

```
- (void)function {
Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedInstance]
[singleton doSomethingWithData:someData
                 target:self
               selector:@selector(processResult:)];
}

- (void)processResult:(id)data {
…
}
```

I'm not sure if my implementation in `doSomethingWithData:untilDoneReturnToTarget:selector:` has fallen into retain-cycle? Should I use `weakTarget` instead of `target` in the block implementation? Please help me clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no retain cycle in your code as far as I can see. But you are extending target's lifecycle until you finish processing data.

If you want to keep the same behaviour but issue a callback only if target is still around, use weak reference

Here is a good article that might help http://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/05/demystifying-retain-cycles-in-arc/

**Update**: one of the most common cases for retain cycle is mutual strong reference: object → block and block → object. Sometimes you can even introduce it not knowingly by using API that would internally create a retain cycle if you are not careful, e.g. ReactiveCocoa (that's why they even have macros to fight it called `weakify` and `strongify`).

Comment: My code does not have retain cycle because there is strong reference from the block to the view controller but no reference from the view controller to the block. Is that right? By the way, thanks for the link, really helps.

Comment: So, the 2 reasons that my code does not raise a retain-cycle are: 1) `doSomethingWithData:untilDoneReturnToTarget:selector:` in `Singleton` calls `doSomething:completionHandler:`, which is a static function of  `someClass`, so this is a local block as specified in [link](http://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/05/demystifying-retain-cycles-in-arc/)    2) As you mention, a retain cycle is created if A-->B and B-->A (both are strong), in my case: A-->B and B-->C (A: singleton, B: block generated by `someClass`, C: view controller). Do you agree with me?

Comment: I'm not sure of the `someClass`, as it is not clear where did it come from and what's the implementation of `doSomething:completionHandler:` That's why I'm failing to reason both about 1) and 2). The easiest way to check if there is a retain cycle, if it is too hard/impossible to reason of the implementation, would be to turn singleton into a regular instance and see if it and target are being deallocated, after the call.

Comment: Actually, `someClass` is `NSURLConnection` and the function is `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler`. I thought it would be simpler if I "model" my code/function, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a singleton, it won't get deallocated anyway, even if there's no retain cycle.